# How we add or change formula for debit and credit in account.move file (odoo14)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I want that the debit and credit value is calculated from subtotal directly not from quantity * price_unit, so I will change its formula by this code..

```
def _get_price_total_and_subtotal(self, price_subtotal=None, quantity=None, discount=None, currency=None, product=None,
                                      partner=None, taxes=None, move_type=None):
        self.ensure_one()
        return self._get_price_total_and_subtotal_model(
            price_subtotal=self.price_subtotal if price_subtotal is None else price_subtotal,
            quantity=self.quantity if quantity is None else quantity,
            discount=self.discount if discount is None else discount,
            currency=self.currency_id if currency is None else currency,
            product=self.product_id if product is None else product,
            partner=self.partner_id if partner is None else partner,
            taxes=self.tax_ids if taxes is None else taxes,
            move_type=self.move_id.move_type if move_type is None else move_type,
        )

    @api.model
    def _get_price_total_and_subtotal_model(self, price_subtotal, quantity, discount, currency, product, partner, taxes,
                                            move_type):
        ''' This method is used to compute 'price_total' & 'price_subtotal'.

        :param price_subtotal:  The current price subtotal.
        :param quantity:    The current quantity.
        :param discount:    The current discount.
        :param currency:    The line's currency.
        :param product:     The line's product.
        :param partner:     The line's partner.
        :param taxes:       The applied taxes.
        :param move_type:   The type of the move.
        :return:            A dictionary containing 'price_subtotal' & 'price_total'.
        '''
        res = {}

        # Compute 'price_subtotal'.
        line_discount_price_unit = price_subtotal * (1 - (discount / 100.0))
        subtotal = line_discount_price_unit

        # Compute 'price_total'.
        if taxes:
            taxes_res = taxes._origin.with_context(force_sign=1).compute_all(line_discount_price_unit,
                                                                             quantity=quantity, currency=currency,
                                                                             product=product, partner=partner,
                                                                             is_refund=move_type in (
                                                                                 'out_refund', 'in_refund'))
            res['price_subtotal'] = taxes_res['total_excluded']
            res['price_total'] = taxes_res['total_included']
        else:
            res['price_total'] = res['price_subtotal'] = subtotal
        # In case of multi currency, round before it's use for computing debit credit
        if currency:
            res = {k: currency.round(v) for k, v in res.items()}
        return res
```

In above code debit / credit value is now getting from subtotal directly not from quantity * unit_price thats allI want but when , I create bill its skip payment register method and automatically set to staus paid instead of in payment..please tell me if above code is wrong then how we change formula for debit and credit in account.move file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating a Vendor Bill automatically Sets the status to Paid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596778/validating-a-vendor-bill-automatically-sets-the-status-to-paid)